# jQuery validation - Select only one option between 3 select boxes

Tags: jquery

Good Day

I have 3 select boxes. Now what i would like to do is allow a user to only select a value in one of the boxes, but not more than one box. The boxes may all be empty.

So yo can have one of the following selected to let the submit be successful:

None(---)
OR
1/2 /3
OR
Blue/Green/Purple 
OR
Big/Medium/Small

```
<select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option>Green</option>
      <option>Purple</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <select>
      <option>---</option>
      <option>Big</option>
      <option>Medium</option>
      <option>Small</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
```

jQuery

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){

$('select').each(function() {
     var i = 0;
     if($(this).attr('option','selected').val() != "---"){
        i++;
     };
  });

if(i > 1){
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        alert('You can only choose one option!');
}
else {
        alert('Form Submitted successfully');
}

});
```

But this does not work at all.

**See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DzUV/16/)**

Comment: you need to add value attribute to your options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean that:

http://jsfiddle.net/2DzUV/18/

```
 $('select').on('change', function () {
        $('select').not(this).val("");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your `i` before`each` function to make it global scope inside your `click` function and accessible in `if` condition:

```
var i = 0;
$('select').each(function() {
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DzUV/20/)**

Answer (score 1):

that is because scope of variable `i` is being reset when iterating through list of `<select>` elements. Move line 4 `var i = 0;` to line 2, i.e. outside the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the creation of the variable i outside of the each function, like below:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){

var i = 0; // <-- this was moved to here
$('select').each(function() {
     if($(this).attr('option','selected').val() != "---"){
        i++;
     };
  });

if(i > 1){
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        alert('You can only choose one option!');
}
else {
        alert('Form Submitted successfully');
}

});
```

Since it was created inside of the each function it is destroyed after that function is exited and the value isn't there anymore when you test for it to be greater than one.